# Using functions within *ngFor loop possible?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a project that basically creates a dynamic table with two input rows and cols. I am now trying to assign random numbers to each cell on creation but I want to make use of the `*ngFor` loop. I currently have :

```html
<td *ngFor="let columnsArrays of columnsArray"
    style="border: 1px solid black;">
    {{ randStr }}
</td>
```

This won't work as intended as the random value is used in each cell repeatedly and not creating a unique value per unique cell.

Is there any way I can use a function within the `*ngFor` loop so that the randomly generated variable differs from loop to loop?

Comment: use ng-repeat , hope it works.

Comment: It is discouraged to use functions inside your templates. Better to compute the values before rendering the HTML. For example in either your constructor, or one of the lifecycle hooks like ngOnInit or ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just encapsulate the random number inside a function and execute it every time you need a new value.

I.e.

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black;"*ngFor="let x of columnsArray">{{ generateRandom() }}</td>
```

---

```
generateRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgjj1e)

Comment: it's discouraged to use functions in bindings. your function will be called on every change detection cycle and angular runs x2 cycles in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use function inside `*ngFor`

```
<tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <th>State</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let country of Countries">
  <td>{{country.country_name}}</td>
  <td>
      <span *ngFor="let state of getStates(country.country_id)">
      {{state.state_name}}
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is idea of using function inside `*ngFor`.
Hope this will help you.